# Model-View-Controller -- Where does a factory class go?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, python, mvc

I'm working (slowly) on a small Flask project. One of my models is a class called `Post`, which is a lightweight `namedtuple`. `Post` objects are created by a `PostFactory`, because creating a `Post` involves hitting a database. The `PostFactory` holds the necessary database connection, so the `Post` objects can be serialized.

What part of the model/view/controller division does a factory object naturally fit in? Is it part of the models, since it's tightly coupled with `Post` objects? Or is it a controller, since it manipulates models?

Comment: If you're using the word "Factory" to refer to an implementation of the Factory OOP design pattern, you might want to rename your class. Object oriented factory pattern isn't what you're doing. See Robert Harvey's answer.

Comment: @RibaldEddie: Yes, that was my intention. Does it not qualify because it only produces objects of one type? I originally had `Post` objects get passed a connection to the database and then pull the necessary info, but it seemed messy because posts have nothing to do with database connections. I thought that the thing that made `Post` objects should be a `PostFactory`, do you think that could be confusing because it's too limited? Is there a more reasonable name for "the class whose instances are used to create `Post` objects"?

Comment: More or less, that's right. But I do wonder what's up with your system. Why is creating an object requiring creating a database record?  Or when you say "create a post object" do you mean something like "save a post object or persist a post?"

Comment: @RibaldEddie: it's the opposite. `Post` objects contain data that's been scraped from another site. They get passed an ID to look up, then pull down information about it from an API.

Comment: Are there any special steps your code needs to do to the Post object between the API call and returning the populated Post? If not, then just put the code in the repository.  If so then rename your Factory to be a Builder. Look up the builder pattern.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's probably a proper part of a repository, which goes in your model.

Any machinery that helps you look up domain objects is part of the model.  The controller will most likely call a method in your repository, which in turn calls the factory to get the `Post` object.  Or, you can expose the factory method from your repository, and allow the controller to call it directly.

Always favor fatter models, and thinner controllers.

Answer (score 1):

The name MVC is highly semantic. Model is your data, View is your UI/Interface, and Controller being the operations you perform on the data. In your example, your assumption is correct in that it would be considered part of the controller as it is manipulating the data.

Comment: See the update I made to my answer.